# MVC 3 - display value from dictionary in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dictionary, razor

I suspect this is simple and I'm just missing it.

I have a view model that has a dictionary as one of its properties.  This dictionary is for populating an HTML select with the Category when I'm editing a record.  There is also a property to indicate the selected CategoryID.  However, when I'm just displaying the record I want to display the value of the key/value pair that corresponds with the CategoryID.

My view model:

```
public class ItemEditVM
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> CategorySelect { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried something like this but I've got the function parameters wrong:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CategorySelect.TryGetValue(model.CategoryID, out val))
```

I've also tried this which fails with no specific error message:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CategorySelect.SingleOrDefault(c=> int.Parse(c.Value) == model.CategoryID).Value)
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks

THE CORRECT ANSWER (Thanks to Mystere Man)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.CategorySelect[Model.CategoryID.Value])
```

Comment: One quick note - I didn't design this database and in the Item table the CategoryID is an FK but can also accept nulls.  I didn't know you could do that.  Anyway, to not violate the FK, in reality the CategoryID will always be populated.

Comment: Of course FK's can be null.  PK's can't be null.  An FK that's null just means there's no relationship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
@Model.CategorySelect[Model.CategoryID.Value]
```

Since as you say, CategoryID won't be null, then this should not be a problem.. unless it could be null, in which case you need to do some validation.

Comment: Actually I did and it gives me an overload error (some invalid arguments)

Comment: @BKahuna - That shouldn't be, there is only one argument to a dictionary indexer, which is the value.  Did you include the .Value? Did you make sure to use UPPER case M on Model?

Comment: Nope, I forgot that.  Why do I need the .value?  I've posted the correct answer above in my original question.  @Mystere - thanks for the help!

Comment: @BKahuna - It's a nullable type, which means to access the value you have to access .Value.

Answer (score 6):

```
@foreach(var keyValue in Model.CategorySelect.keys)
{
   foreach(var cat in @Model.CategorySelect[keyValue]
   {
      <p>@cat</p> <!--whatever html you fancy--> 
   }
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to give you a different way.